# Inconsistent Graphics Resolution

Tags: linux, x11, resolution

I have one Linux workstation that has a handful of user accounts. Some of the accounts run the GUI with acceptable resolutions and some of them are "locked" into a ridiculously low resolution with no options for changing it.

If I log into any of the desktops from a remote computer, the resolution is fine, but if a user logs in to one of the affected accounts locally, the screen resolution is very low (640x480) and cannot be adjusted using the GUI.

Not all accounts with local logins are affected, some work fine. From what I've seen, all the accounts display properly using remote connections.

From a local login with "good" resolution, I get this as the result of running "*xranr -q*":

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1600x1000     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

but if I run "xrandr -q" from an affected account I get:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

I don't see any individual configuration files for the X server in either user's account and all the accounts were, at one time, working consistently as expected...

Is this a configuration issue or is it that some of the users accounts are not picking up the capabilities of the monitor (...while some are...)? How can one user detect the monitor correctly and another fail to do so?

Anyone have any ideas how I can fix this (without having to reinstall or anything drastic)?

Comment: maybe it is some kind of a setting for the visually impaired that is being activated

Comment: @jsotola I hadn't thought of that...but shouldn't the monitor's capabilities be picked up the same in either case?

Comment: it was only a thought about the visual setting ......... i am not super knowledgeable about the subject .... i think that you are right about the monitor capability .... the other thought that pops up is that the affected users do not have the permission to set the resolution, so the screen resolution stays at the default setting for them ..... perhaps a lack of a membership in a group is the problem ......... it could be caused by the way the users were created

Comment: Never did figure this out. Shortly after I posted this question the workstation's root disk drive "bought the farm"... so I had to reinstall the O/S on a new drive and everything has been good ever since. Could have been related to coming drive problems I guess... but that seems doubtful.